# How to only compile the included tex file?

Tags: compiling

Suppose we are given a big main .tex file. I wish to use the command  \include to import all the other .tex files into the mail .tex file. I heard that to save time, one can in fact only compile the particular file included. But how can I do that if the included .tex file does not have a document class or proper setup for it to typeset on its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\includeonly` command:

```
\documentclass{book}
\includeonly{nextfile}
\begin{document}
  \include{somefile}
  \include{someotherfile}
  \include{nextfile}
\end{document}
```

Now only the `nextfile` will be compiled but all the numbers and other cross reference are properly displayed.